# Domain error in python math.acos with valid input

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

```
def dot(x, y):
    return sum([ x[i]*y[i] for i in range(1,10)])

def magnitude(x):
    return math.sqrt(sum([x[i]*x[i] for i in range(1,10)]))

def cosine_similarity(x, y):
    x = dot(x, y) / (magnitude(x)*magnitude(y))
    print(x)
    print(math.acos(x))
    return math.acos(x) / math.pi
```

This is my python code. I am trying to find the angle between two vectors represented as lists. When I run this code, the output is:

```
1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "problem5.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(cosine_similarity(reservoir[0][0], reservoir[0][0]))
  File "problem5.py", line 41, in cosine_similarity
    print(math.acos(x))
ValueError: math domain error
```

If I type in my console or file 
    math.acos(1.0)
It accurately gives me 0. I have done type checking, etc and everything seems to check out.

Comment: You are overwriting parameter `x`. Avoid it

Comment: Running that code does nothing visible. Please show code (perhaps reduced to a small size) that calls your `cosine_similarity()` function and gives the error. Reference [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What version of Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encounter rounding issues. `x` can take values like `1.0000000000000002` due to float rounding errors, so it trig an error. you can replace `math.acos` by `numpy.acos` to silently observe what append.